# iOS: Change UITableView height under Auto Layout

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, autolayout

Is there a way to change the height of a UITableView programmatically if you're using Auto Layout? I have a view controller that has to use Auto Layout. It also contains a UITableView, but the table view doesn't seem to respond to setFrame calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own constraints programmatically. Refer to Apple's documentation on [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010628) for more information on how to do this.

Comment: Ah I see! I need to set a height constraint. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely view the WWDC 2012 videos on the topic of Auto Layout on developer.apple.com.  The videos are:

- Session 202 - Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X
- Session 228 - Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout
- Session 232 - Auto Layout by Example

The videos show how to setup the constraints in code, using the visual description language and in IB.  They also cover some "gotchas" when transitioning to Auto-Layout.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to suck it up and read the manual/watch the WWDC videos.  Not only do they show how to set height constraints in both code and Interface Builder, they also explain the problems you will run into (and so how to avoid them and save yourself time and effort)